# pandas get entries from Series B that are also in Series A; but entries unique only in Series A shall have a fill value of 0

Tags: python, pandas, series

This is a unique kind of join/combine, but I don't know what this is called, so please feel free to correct me with the terminology.

So for example I have a Series `profile` as follows:

```
In [1]: profile = pd.Series(data=[0.8,0.64,0.51,0.5,0.5], index=['google.com','facebook.com','twitter.com', 'instagram.com', 'github.com'])

In [2]: profile
Out[2]: 
google.com       0.80
facebook.com     0.64
twitter.com      0.51
instagram.com    0.50
github.com       0.50
dtype: float6
```

And I have a `transaction` Series as follows:

```
In [3]: transaction = pd.Series(data=[1,1,1,1], index=['twitter.com','facebook.com','instagram.com','9gag.com'])

In [4]: transaction
Out[4]: 
twitter.com      1
facebook.com     1
instagram.com    1
9gag.com         1
dtype: int64
```

What I want to achieve is a Series `window` where I compare both the `profile` and `transaction`: where if an index in `transaction` exists also in `profile`, we get that certain index and it's respective value. The remaining indices that are unique only in `profile` shall have fill values of 0.

```
In [5]: window
Out[5]: 
google.com       0
facebook.com     1
twitter.com      1
instagram.com    1
github.com       0
dtype: int64
```

Is there any existing built-in methods/functions that can do this?

I have experimented with:

```
window = transaction[transaction.keys().isin(profile.keys())]
```

but it only returns the intersection of the `transaction` and `profile`.
I came upon this `combine()` function in the `Series` but I don't know what to apply in the `func` parameter (`isin()` is invalid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v. 0.17.0 of Pandas, you can reindex the series.

```
>>> transaction.reindex(profile.index).fillna(0)
google.com       0
facebook.com     1
twitter.com      1
instagram.com    1
github.com       0
dtype: float64
```

It also appears to be slightly faster than using `loc`, although I haven't tested this on a larger dataframe.

```
%timeit transaction.reindex(profile.index).fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 224 µs per loop

%timeit transaction.loc[profile.index].fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 329 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is better. It does not get a Key Error if none in `transaction` are in `profile`.